# Is my flow good enough for securing REST API?

Tags: facebook, rest, api, backend

I'm new in web development. I want to write a backend for my game and I want to authenticate it with Facebook. I'm not sure if my thinking is correct and secure enought. Of course https is a must.

1. User everytime app is launched sends /init request with fb user id and token.
2. Server check if this user id and token is valid by making request to fb api.
3. If everything is correct server check for user in database.
4. If user do not exists generate token using app secret, fb token, fb id and current date/time save it to database and send to client.
   OR If user with this fb id exists send to user previously generated token stored in database.
5. Client is communicating with api using this token.

If this approach is correct I have few question.
Is sending user id and token everytime user launch application secure?
I want to veryfi user token and id with fb every time he use /init request due to fb access tokens not beeing alive for more than 60 days. Is this correct approach?
Now if user have his token to access my API. Every time he make a request should I veryfi it by making calls to database? Isn't this slow/expensive?

Comment: I think you're looking for OpenID Connect. You should read on that protocol. It fit your needs perfectly so you can apply it straightforward. I don't know your development stack but I recommend IdentifyServer (for .NET).

Comment: Thanks for response. I will definetly look up OpenID.